# expo is out of date uninstall and run again to upgrade

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

when running my app on ios simulator, I am getting the following error `This version of the Expo app is out of date. Uninstall the app and run again to upgrade.`

Here is how I tried to upgrade expo-cli yet not successful

1. `npm update -g`
2. `yarn add global expo-cli`
3. `npm uninstall expo-cli`
4. `npm cache clean --force`
5. `yarn add global expo-cli`

Here is app.json

```
"expo": {
    "name": "firebase-reacte-native",
    "slug": "firebase-reacte-native",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
    ....
```

Here is package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
  }
```

All I want to do is run ios-simulator without the error message on ios simulator as `there was a problem loading the requested app. The experience you requested requires a newer version of the Expo Client app.`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The issue is to do with the app that is on the iOS simulator / device is out of date and is not compatible with the current version of Expo that you running.

Delete the Expo app from the the iOS simulator and it should work, or install the latest update if you are on a device

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1595

One way to do it is with the simulator open is to `Erase All Content and Settings`. Then re-run npm start and the Expo App will be installed again on this device simulator.

[image]

Comment: This is on a simulator - what to do on an actual physical device?

Comment: As I mention in my answer `install the latest update if you are on a device`. So you should probably download the latest version from the App Store. If that doesn't work and you still have issues then you should open an issue with Expo on their Github.

Comment: On the iOS emulator, deleting the expo app from the simulator as suggested worked like a charm! For the Android emulator, I had to wipe data through Android Studio. I'm happy to be back in action! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Please, try this:

```
1.- npm cache clean -f
2.- yarn upgrade
3.- npm upgrade
3.- npm install
```

If this doesn't work try edit **package.json**:

```
{
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
  "expo": "^34.0.1",
  "react": "16.8.3"
}
```

Then

```
npm install
```

let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew update sovled my probolem!

`brew upgrade node`

Answer (score 2):

Expo seems to detect the outdated version and suggests to update it for you in the console when you run `expo start`:

```sh
› Opening exp://192.168.1.231:19000 on Pixel_3a_API_30_x86
✔ Expo Go on Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 (emulator) is outdated, would you like to upgrade? … yes
Uninstalling Expo Go from Android device.
```

All I had to do was to press <kbd>Y</kbd> and it updated automatically.